# How can I switch between 2 shaders without adding more and more draw calls?

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, rendering

I would like to create a renderer class that can switch between 2 or more shaders without adding more and more draw calls.

What I mean is to have 2 shaders - A and B - and method that takes shader, position, size to create for example a quad.

and I want to add that data (position, size) and pass it to vertex A (so it is 1st draw calls), then add another data to vertex B(so it is 2nd draw call) and again add data to shader A (so it still should be 2 draw calls, because we have already used shader A somewhere before). And at the end go though draw calls and draw a scene.

I have a RenderData class that adds draw calls, vertex, element data, etc.

```
struct DrawCall
{
    //it may have more data like texture, clip rect, camera, etc.
    Shader* shader = nullptr;
};

struct Vertex
{
    Vector2 position;
}

class RenderData
{
public:
    RenderData();
    ~RenderData();

    void Free() {           
    vertexBuffer.clear();
    shader.clear();
    drawCall.clear();
    elementBuffer.clear();
    }

    void Draw(const Rect& dest);

    void AddDrawCall();
    inline DrawCall* getDrawCall() { return drawCall.size() > 0 ? &drawCall.back() : nullptr; }

    void UpdateShader();
    void PushShader(Shader* shader);
    void PopShader();
    inline Shader* getShader() { return shader.size() > 0 ? shader.back() : nullptr; }

    uint currentVertexIndex = 0;

    vector<Vertex> vertexBuffer;   // Vertex data
    vector<Shader*> shader;
    vector<DrawCall> drawCall;
    vector<uint> elementBuffer; // Index data
}

void RenderData::AddDrawCall()
{
    DrawCall dc;
    dc.shader = getShader();
    drawCall.push_back(dc);
}

void RenderData::UpdateShader()
{
    Shader* currentShader = getShader();
    DrawCall* currentDraw = getDrawCall();
    if (!currentDraw || currentDraw->shader != currentShader) {
        AddDrawCall();
        return;
    }

    DrawCall* prevDraw = drawCall.size() > 1 ? currentDraw - 1 : nullptr;
    if (prevDraw->shader == currentShader) {
        drawCall.pop_back();
    } else { currentDraw->shader = currentShader; }
}

void RenderData::PushShader(Shader* shader)
{
    this->shader.push_back(shader);
    UpdateShader();
}

void RenderData::PopShader()
{
    Custom_Assert(shader.size() > 0, "Cannot PopShader() with size < 0!\n");
    shader.pop_back();
    UpdateShader();
}

void RenderData::Draw(const Rect& dest)
{
    //dest -> x, y, w and h
    //setup vertices 
    vertexBuffer.push_back(...);
    vertexBuffer.push_back(...);
    vertexBuffer.push_back(...);
    vertexBuffer.push_back(...);

    //setup elements
    elementBuffer.push_back(...);
    elementBuffer.push_back(...);
    elementBuffer.push_back(...);
    elementBuffer.push_back(...);
    elementBuffer.push_back(...);
    elementBuffer.push_back(...);
}
```

and Renderer2D class which has few objects:
vao, vbo, ebo, RenderData
and few methods:

`Create()` -> it creates ebo and ebo

`RenderClear()` -> it `Free()` RenderData, sets up viewport

`RenderPresent` -> it creates and binds vao, binds vbo, adds vbo attributes and data, binds ebo and adds ebo data, and goes through `DrawCall& drawCall : renderData.drawCall`, uses shader program and draws elements;

```
void Renderer2D::Create()
{     
    //gens and binds
    vbo = vbo->Create(TYPE::ARRAY, USAGE::DYNAMIC_DRAW));
    //gens and binds
    ebo = ebo->Create(TYPE::ELEMENT, USAGE::DYNAMIC_DRAW));
}

void Renderer2D::RenderClear()
{
    setRenderViewport(0, 0, 1280, 720);
    renderData.Free();
}

    void Renderer2D::RenderPresent()
{
    vao = vao->Create();

    vbo->BindBuffer();

    vbo->AddAttribute(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex), (const void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));

    vbo->AddData(renderData.vertexBuffer.size() * sizeof(Vertex), renderData.vertexBuffer.data());

    ebo->BindBuffer();
    ebo->AddData(renderData.elementBuffer.size() * sizeof(uint), renderData.elementBuffer.data());

    for (auto& drawCall : renderData.drawCall) {
        drawCall.shader->UseProgram();

        vao->DrawElements(drawCall.elemCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
    }

    //delete vertex array
    vao->Free();
}
```

how it works:

```
int main()
{
    Renderer2D renderer2D;
    renderer2D.Create();

    Shader A("shader.vtx", "shader.frag");
    Shader B("shader.vtx", "shader2.frag");

    while(!quit) {
        renderer2D.RenderClear();

        //Push A shader = add 1st draw call
        renderer2D->PushShader(&A);
        renderer2D->Draw({ 100.0f, 100.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f });
        renderer2D->PopShader();

        //Push B shader = add 2nd draw call
        renderer2D->PushShader(&B);
        renderer2D->Draw({ 200.0f, 200.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f });
        renderer2D->PopShader();

        //Push A shader = do not add 3rd draw call, use already existing one
        //This version adds 3rd draw call instead of using existing one
        renderer2D->PushShader(&A);
        renderer2D->Draw({ 400.0f, 400.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f });
        renderer2D->PopShader();

        renderer2D.RenderPresent();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to change it, somehow, to work as I described, but I do not know how (if it is even possible) to do it.

Comment: Try using `static const Shader * shader;`... inside the structure and then use it like `draw_call::shader` every time... Instead of having to add draw calls, you can just replace them with this singleton structure that is re-assigned and re-used inside the loop...

Comment: Are the "draw calls" order dependent? Or would it be possible to sort the "draw calls" by the shaders A and B?

Comment: @Ruks ` Instead of having to add draw calls, you can just replace them with this singleton structure that is re-assigned and re-used inside the loop...` I do not exactly understand this part.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I would like it to be order dependent, because of sprite rendering order (I do not know exactly how to call it, let's say "z-buffer"-effect).

Comment: @ANewGuy In this case, this what you want to achieve is not possible. But why do upload the vertex coordinates to the buffer in every frame? Why do you create the vertex buffer and vertex array objects in every frame? Why do you need 2 different shaders? Why is it not possible to use 1 shader program and uniforms which "configure" the shader program? I think you are asking about a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) .

Comment: @Rabbid76 I want to render text with signed distance field algorithm and still be able to use the same renderer to draw textured sprites, so I need 2 shaders, but I do not want to create a separate class for text rendering. Recreate the VAO every time - This is to easily allow multiple GL contexts. VAO are not shared among GL contexts, and we don't track creation/deletion of windows so we don't have an obvious key to use to cache them

Comment: @ANewGuy With a modern hardware it may be cheeper to switch the shader by uniform conditions instead of changing the shader program. Do you konw about [Shader Subroutine](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Subroutine)? Furher it is possible that a program object contains [Separate programs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Separate_programs)

Comment: That may be a solution. I will take a closer look tomorrow. Thanks for help!